# What animal is this? A bee? red mason bee? (Bee-like with brown/orange fur)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

The picture was taken at the Bodensee (Lake Constance) in Southwestern Germany in June 2019. I tried to Google "Bee with brown fur", but the only thing that came up was a red mason bee, and the resulting pictures didn't look *quite* like this photo

Since I was sent the photo, I don't know the actual size of the insect.

[image: strange bee-like animal with orange/brown fur sitting on wood]

Comment: Definitely a bee, I'd guess from the family apidae. Do you have other photos? Getting a good ID will probably require a sharper photo.